# How to put lines from a scroll field to datagrid?

Tags: livecode

How to put lines from a scroll field to datagrid?. Now, iam using this code. but in this code i used 'set' command instead of 'put' and its works fine. How to use 'put' command in this code.

```
on mouseUp
   repeat with x = 0 to the number of lines in field "MytextField" 
      if line x of field "MytextField" contains the text in field "SearchField" then
         put line x-1 of field "MytextField" & cr & line x of field "MytextField" & cr & line x+1 of field "MytextField" into  bbb       
         set the dgText of group "DGP" to bbb
      end if 
   end repeat
end mouseUp
```

DGP is the grid name. This two codes i already used. but it doesn't work

```
put bbb into dgText of group "DGP" to bbb
put bbb after dgText of group "DGP" to bbb
```

I also need this after keyword to put lines back to back to the grid.

Answer (score 0):

`dgText` is a property and properties are modified with the 'set' command. The datagrid doesn't have a `text` property, which is the only property that can be modified with the `put`command.

For example:

```
put url "/path/to/image.jpg" into img 1
put the text of img 1
--> returns the picture data in message box

put "This is some text" into grp "Data Grid"
--> error: no such property

put the text of grp "Data Grid"
--> error: no such property
```

To set the `dgText` of a datagrid to the lines directly before and after the hilited line including the hilited line itself, follow this example:

```
on mouseUp
     put the hilitedline of fld "List A" into myLineNr
     put line myLineNr-1 to myLineNr+1 of fld "List A" into myText
     set the dgText of grp 1 to myText
end mouseUp
```

First, we store the number of the hilited line. The lines we want are lines `myLineNr-1 to myLineNr+1`, e.g. `line 3 to 5 of fld "List A"`. We store the text of these lines in `myText` and set the `dgText` of the datagrid to `myText`. Setting the `dgText` of a datagrid is the equivalent of putting text into a field. This example assumes that your datagrid is the first group of the current card of your stack.

Comment: so, How to put text in the data grid? {put "This is some text" into grp "DGP"} not working. I need to fetch the text (x-1, x and x+1)  from scrolling field to data grid. if the text occurred more than 1 times in scrolling field  then, i need to fetch the same back to back(after the lines).

Comment: I don't know what back to back implies, but I have update my reply to answer your question as well as possible.